# Programming language criterion for coding mistakes

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages

When comparing programming languages and IDEs, I think there is one criterion that is never mentioned and I think is very important.

**Question :**

Do you know if there exist a definition of this criterion (which I'm going to define)? Please provide references.

The criterion, which I'll call "coding mistakes index", represents the number of coding mistakes that will be caught by the programming environment before runtime.

It’s a percentage, as related to the IDE+language.

For example, a hello world in Eclipse+java: if I delete one of the bold letters, an error message is presented.

> **package main;**
>   **public class Main{**
>         **public static void main(String[]** args **){**
>         **System.out.println("** Hello Horld **");**
>         **}**
>   **}**

In this example: there are 91 bold letters out of 106 letters which make 86%.

Comment: The closest I can think of is documented in "Code Complete" as Bugs per lines of code - or `# of defects per KLOC`. It's not a very good metric.

Comment: There's also an incredibly large number of ways that an extra character could break this code. I don't know if there's a way to calculate this metric and it actually be useful. Logic errors are far more important (and harder to catch) than syntax errors.

Comment: Ever tried coding in Agda? Highly recommended!

Comment: That doesn't sound a very useful metric for comparing IDEs. Most IDEs catch *all* errors that would prevent the code from compiling (given full source code and libraries). Anyway, in your example wouldn't an IDE that detects an error in the bolded part of the code mean it catches 100% of mistakes? Changing string contents can hardly be considered a mistake the IDE should (or could) detect.

Comment: This kind of question is at the heart of the dynamic/static split. Rather than being under-addressed, I'd say that if anything this criterion gets too much attention, and edges out other aspects of the usability of programming languages.

Answer (score 3):

From my personal experience, I'd have to say that's a very useless metric. The number of syntax errors caught by the compiler or interpreter before runtime is 100% for all languages. What you've demonstrated is a syntax error.

Syntax errors usually happen when you're learning a language. Or when you're programming in a language that you haven't touched in a while. Generally, a proficient programmer will internalize the language's syntax and avoid them while typing. For example, C programmers quickly learn to end statements with `;` and Lisp programmers quickly learn to keep track of braces (usually by learning to neatly indent code).

In industry, such trivial language detail as syntax or types are very, very rarely the cause of bugs even in languages with minimal syntax or have no type systems. Most bugs you'll encounter are in the form of:

```
package main;
public class Main{
   public static void main(String[] args ){
     System.out.println(" Goodbye World ");
   }
}
```

See what I did there? The bug is the use of the word "Goodbye" instead of "Hello". Bugs are rarely accidental - buggy code almost always look correct and intentional and almost always compile without errors (otherwise they'll be called compile errors not bugs). Bugs are usually caused by a misunderstanding of what the code should do.

Another reason it's a useless metric is different languages have different levels of verbosity. Of the following two examples:

Example 1:

```
package main;
public class Main{
   public static void main(String[] args ){
     System.out.prntln(" Hello World ");
   }
}
```

Example 2:

```
prnt " Hello World \n";
```

Both examples are exactly the same program in different languages with exactly the same bug. But example 1 would have a higher "coding mistakes index" while example 2 would have a lower index. This is simply because there's less code in example 2 to begin with therefore syntax errors account for a lower percentage of the typed characters.

But from a readability standpoint a human can easily spot the mistake in example 2 without even running the compiler or using an IDE while the mistake in example 1 is easily overlooked.

This means that the coding mistakes index is not only not useful but can even be misleading by giving a potentially better language a lower score.

How useful is a benchmark/metric is directly related to how likely it is to exist. A useless metric is unlikely to be used and therefore is unlikely to be invented/exist. A metric that's completely wrong is very likely to be ignored by everyone even if someone invents it.

Comment: In case you're wondering, Example 2 is perfectly valid Perl code without the "bug". But there are several other languages where it's also valid code.

Comment: You claim that: "The number of syntax errors caught by the compiler or interpreter before runtime is 100% for all languages" which is not true.
This javascript on notepad++ does not display any error message althogh it is nonsense.
fnction myFunction(){alet("Hello World!");}
About whether or not it's a useful metric, I dont want to get into it.
I'm convinced that this is the first thing I want to know about a language.
The question is about whether this metric exists, I'm looking for references.

Comment: My browser says: `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`. So does node.js. Deliberately ignoring compiler errors by not looking at it is not the same as the compiler not generating errors.